# Using SVA, how can we write a property to check that we are not getting two req (req1 and req2) at the same time

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

Both `req1` and `req2` are asynchronous. And I want to check that at no point in the simulation, `req2` is true while `req1` is true. I have tried

```
property not_req2_while_req1;
    @(negedge req1)
    1 |-> $stable(req2);
endproperty
ASSERT_NOT_REQ2_WHILE_REQ1:assert property (not_req2_while_req1);
```

but it seems to not give the desired results. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you stated your requirements correctly as what you wrote does not even come close to expressing that, but the following SVA code matches what you said.

```
ASSERT_NOT_REQ2_WHILE_REQ1: assert final (req1 -> !req2);
```

**EDIT:**
You edited your question to simply require that both req1 and req2 never be true at the same time. That is a NAND operation

```
ASSERT_NAND_REQ2_REQ1: assert final ( !(req1&&req2) );
```

Comment: Hey Dave, that was my first attempt at writing an assertion. What you suggested works for 1 case but it does not cover the following two cases which are possible with the design that I have at hand: 1. When `req2` high/ON time is as much as `req1's` high/ON time and both are asserted at the same time. 2. When `req2` is asserted after `req1` is asserted, and `req2` is also de-asserted before `req1` is de-asserted.

Comment: What I wrote should work for those cases. I’m using the Boolean implies operator `->`, not property implication `|->`

Comment: I have tried it on a mock design - 
[https://edaplayground.com/x/6bhB](https://edaplayground.com/x/6bhB)

Comment: works correctly for me. You might have to go back and edit your question since I think you many be using the word *asserted* for both a level and an edge. Please use *true* and *false* for a level and *rising* and *falling* for an edge.

Comment: Correcting my selection of words and putting the two uncovered scenarios again below - 
1. When `req2` and `req1` rising and falling edge coincide such thst there true time is equal. (40ns-50ns & 60ns-70ns in mock code shared above)
2. When `req2` rising edge is after `req1's` rising edge and also `req2` falling edge is before the falling edge of `req1` (120ns-130ns)